# spring boot rest ResponseEntity responses

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

Fairly new to spring boot rest and have questions regarding the how and the best way to handle responses to the client using the service.  Currently, I have the following controller code for handling the case of a record not being found in a database query:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
@GetMapping("distance/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getDistanceById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    log.info("getDistanceById");
    Distance distance = distanceService.getDistanceById(id);
    if (distance == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorMsg>(new CustomErrorMsg("Distance ID " + id + " Not Found"),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Distance>(distance, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Where CustomErrorMsg is a simple class that sets a String in it's constructor.

Is this the best approach?  Would a ControllerAdvice based class be a better aproach?  Asking this question because the code above sends an expected 403 response when called by a cient without permission. Would like understand how that is occuring and if it can be used for a NOT FOUND condition.

Comment: 403 is sent by Spring framework since because of @PreAuthorize. For Not found, you can do this by using exceptionhandler advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Resource not found" is a well-known use case, for which you don't have to "bother" with ResponseEntity or ControllerAdvice. You can simply use [ResourceNotFoundException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/ResourceNotFoundException.html).

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@GetMapping("distance/{id}")
public Distance getDistanceById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    log.info("getDistanceById");
    Distance distance = distanceService.getDistanceById(id);
    if (distance == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Distance ID " + id + " Not Found");
    }

    return distance;
}
```

Declaring `ResponseEntity<?>` as return type is correct but doesn't convey much information, since you're putting actual data and an error message on the same level. If like me you prefer to use the ResponseEntity static builders, go for :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@GetMapping("distance/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Distance> getDistanceById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    log.info("getDistanceById");
    Distance distance = distanceService.getDistanceById(id);
    if (distance == null){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Distance ID " + id + " Not Found");
    }

    return new ResponseEntity.ok(distance);
}
```

Again, what you're interested in is a Distance (your code probably stands in a class called `DistanceController`), so let's not emphasize when it's not found.

Now, regarding the HTTP status.
If you request `/distance/<id>` with insufficient privileges, you'll get an access denial (403 Forbidden), which is not the same as an unknown resource (404 Not Found) - that is btw the status returned when ResourceNotFoundException is thrown.

Here, permissions to access the requested URL is checked first. If the user is authenticated with insufficient authorities, you get a 403 error. It not, you're free to go, and will get the requested resource (200), unless it doesn't exist (404).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use RestControllerAdvice annotated class (for example named GlobalExceptionHandler) for handling error case. You will need to change getDistanceById method to throw custom exception when distance is null. You will need to add a method to the GlobalExceptionHandler which will handle your custom exception. then you can change your code to the following:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
@GetMapping("distance/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Distance> getDistanceById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    log.info("getDistanceById");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(distanceService.getDistanceById(id));
}
```